# How do I make a drop down filter in a separate cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet and was wondering if anyone knows how to make a drop-down filter in a separate cell. I have a different spreadsheet and that one has a drop-down month filter in a separate cell (so, for example, you pick October and then it shows the order data for every customer for October and you can do the same with November & all the other months) and I want to recreate that, but I don't know where to start. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean separate cell or more specifically in your example? You can do a drop down with validation. Maybe show an expectation? When you mean by `filter`? A data filter or the filter function?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.